# USB Mouse and Keyboard not working after booting (worked until today)

Tags: 12.04, usb

after a cold start it needs some time till my mouse and my keyboard get recognized.
It worked until today.

On this machine it runs a `Linux desktop 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with the latest updates (installed yesterday).

This is the log of my `dmesg`:

```
[   30.608084] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   31.452037] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   31.668020] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[   46.780015] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   61.996013] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   62.212035] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[   72.620030] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 6, error -110
[   72.732036] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[   83.140065] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 7, error -110
[   83.140079] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 6
[   83.404036] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[   83.652566] input: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input10
[   83.652697] generic-usb 0003:046D:C049.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-1/input0
[   83.656357] generic-usb 0003:046D:C049.0002: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-1/input1
[   83.656373] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   83.656375] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   83.832040] usb 4-2: new low-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[   84.022743] input: Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input11
[   84.022847] generic-usb 0003:045E:00DD.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2/input0
[   84.045583] input: Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/input/input12
[   84.045664] generic-usb 0003:045E:00DD.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2/input1
[   84.284066] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[   89.284028] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: Unlink after no-IRQ?  Controller is probably using the wrong IRQ.
```

Notice: Yeah, i found this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74464/usb-mouse-keyboard-not-working), but the bug-report is closed so maybe other people have the same problem.

Thanks in advance,
best

Comment: [Bug Report for something similar](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/991932).

Comment: Same with my external DVD-drive and [ 169.660058] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd [ 169.864099] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [ 170.172078] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [ 170.388078] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd [ 170.592088] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [ 170.900078] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [ 171.116080] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd [ 171.580116] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 12, error -71 [ 171.692087] usb 1-6: new high-spee

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound silly, but try just pulling the power cord out and waiting for 30 seconds and putting it back in and restarting. If you google the error code, you'll find tons of threads on it. This solution worked for me and apparently it has worked for other people as well. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610142&p=10054218#post10054218

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be for everyone, here's what i did to solve this problem for my USB keyboard and mouse. I put a PS2 keyboard and mouse into my computer. They works just fine.

Additionally, i installed a Synergy client on my Ubuntu, so that after i log in, i use the shared mouse and keyboard.

I hope this helps.

Love and peace,

Joe